# Geomesa BBOX query provide result only for whole world BBOX

Tags: cql-filter, geomesa

I am running command line query to get bounding box data. The geomesa query is returning result only if the bounding box is "BBOX(geom, -180, -90, 180, 90.0)". For any other parameter, it is returning 0 features.

I have tried the geomesa hbase guide. GDELT example is giving similar result where it is returning data only for "BBOX(geom, -180, -90, 180, 90.0)".

https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-hbase-s3-on-aws.html#ingest-public-gdelt-data

```
key                    | String 
namespace              | String (Attribute indexed)
identifier             | String (Attribute indexed)
version                | String 
payload                | String 
payload_schema_version | String 
geom                   | Point  (Spatially indexed)

User data:
  geomesa.indices | z2:5:3:geom,id:4:3:,attr:8:3:namespace:geom,attr:8:3:identifier:geom
```

Even below query is returning 0 result althought there is 100GB data for this bounding box exist.

`geomesa-hbase export -c geospatial_data_version_1 -f geospatial_data-point-entity -m 10 -q "BBOX(geom, -179, -90, 180, 90)"`

I am using Geomesa v 2.3.0 and Hbase 1.4.3 on S3.

```
Response:
id,key:String,namespace:String,identifier:String,version:String, payload:String,payload_schema_version:String, *geom:Point:srid=4326

INFO  Feature export complete to standard out in 6163ms for 0 features
```